# How to initialize array to tuple type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array, typescript-typings

I'm making sudoku web app with React/Redux. But I have encountered some problem with typings.

Current code:

```js
// typedef
type Tuple9<T> = [T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T];

export type Board = Tuple9<Tuple9<number>>;

// code using board type, I want to fix getEmptyBoard() to more programmatic.
const getEmptyBoard: (() => Board) = () => {
  return [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  ];
};
```

I want to fix `getEmptyBoard()` to more programmatic.

1. Is there good solution for this situation?
2. If 1, What is solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `9` I would do what you have done.

Otherwise you would follow the old functional programming saying : `If its pure on the outside, it doesn't matter if its impure on the inside` and make a strategic use of `Tuple9` [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html):

```
type Tuple9<T> = [T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T];
function make9<T>(what: T): Tuple9<T> {
    return new Array(9).fill(what) as Tuple9<T>;
}

export type Board = Tuple9<Tuple9<number>>;
function makeBoard(): Board {
    return make9(make9(0));
}
```

Comment: Thx :)
`const getEmptyBoard: (() => Board) = () => new Array(9).fill(0).map(() => new Array(9).fill(0)) as Board;`
This code works!

Answer (score 1):

Types don't exist at runtime meaning that there is no way to say "given type A build run-time Array X"

The more programmatic way to build it would be something like

```
new Array(9).fill(0).map(() => new Array(9).fill(0))
```

Comment: It is one of my solution but doesnt work cuz incompatible type of two.